# asp encryption AES clone to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, encryption

well here is my problem, i have an app in asp and and im encrypting the the password with

```
validationKey="491B78013906183FAD94824D433E97D21C4F95E3A686409CA56720FECB4DDF6F790F89C61D0269512B099BEB94609F646F600863D8D308F5AC28B885BF31F03E" 

decryptionKey="01CB09CAE8FA88C5F8FBCF6D8661BF0FAFA220EBF73911842173764DA9744F31" 
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
```

Now I'm no encrytoguru or anything, and i need to recreate this into php, does anyone has any idea how can i do this??? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [user notes on the mcrypt functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php#99263) in the PHP manual. One user has provided sample code for AES encrypt and decrypt functions in PHP.

Comment: didn't work :( i try with both but it keeps telling me that the key was too long, and i need to recreate this in php so i can have both asp and php encripting password for the db.